# Howto render a Func<Object, TemplateWriter> to string in Razor view engine Html Helper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am not actually using the Razor from ASP.NET MVC, I am using the standalone version as found [here](http://razorengine.codeplex.com)

I have created my own HtmlHelper as described [here](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Building%20Custom%20Base%20Templates&referringTitle=Documentation)

I have determined via trial and error that razor `<text>` attributes produce a `Func<Object, TemplateWriter>` object when called in the context of a method.

The method signature of the helper looks like:

```
    public String IncludeOnce(Func<Object, TemplateWriter> text) {
       //here I need to be able to render the text Func to a string so
       //I can do some checks, and return it if it hasnt yet been included
       //or return an empty string if it has
    }
```

I am invoking it in my template like:

```
    @Html.IncludeOnce(
    @<text>
      <style type="text/css">
        /* styles I only want on the page once, and not everytime the template
           is rendered. Note: I need @Model to work here too*/
        .something { top: @Model.Top }
      </style>
    </text>)
```

How can I get it as a String? Also, If I pass it to another template, eg:

```
      public String IncludeOnce(Func<Object, TemplateWriter> text) {
          return Razor.Parse("other.cshtml", new { Content = text(new Object()) })
      }
```

where `other.cshtml` is:

```
      @Model.Content
```

it works. What does Razor.Parse know that I dont?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the Object parameter is the Model. So, by looking at your code above, I'm pretty sure the following will work:

```
public String IncludeOnce(Func<Object, TemplateWriter> text) {
   string output = text(Model).ToString();

   //Do Stuff

   return output 
}
```

Comment: Wow, cant believe I couldn't figure that out! Thanks!